# Kotlin LocalDateTime as Long

Tags: java, android, kotlin, localdatetime

I am trying to get my LocalDateTime field saved as a long so I can store it in my SQLite database. How am I able to do this?

```
var datetime = LocalDateTime.now()
var longdt: Long = getString(datetime).toLong()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`toEpochSecond()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#toEpochSecond-java.time.ZoneOffset-) and [`ofEpochSecond()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#ofEpochSecond-long-int-java.time.ZoneOffset-) to convert to/from a `long` value with precision to the second.

*Example (in Java)*

```java
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
long nowInSeconds = now.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(nowInSeconds, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);

System.out.println("now = " + now);
System.out.println("nowInSeconds = " + nowInSeconds);
System.out.println("dateTime = " + dateTime);
```

*Output*

```
now = 2020-05-12T12:12:36.984263200
nowInSeconds = 1589285556
dateTime = 2020-05-12T12:12:36
```

If you needed the `long` value with precision to the millisecond, do this:

```java
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
long nowInMillis = now.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) * 1000
                 + now.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND);
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(nowInMillis / 1000,
                  (int) (nowInMillis % 1000 * 1000000), ZoneOffset.UTC);

System.out.println("now = " + now);
System.out.println("nowInMillis = " + nowInMillis);
System.out.println("dateTime = " + dateTime);
```

*Output*

```
now = 2020-05-12T12:16:38.881510700
nowInMillis = 1589285798881
dateTime = 2020-05-12T12:16:38.881
```

If needed, specify a zone offset other than `UTC`, but in that case you should really be using `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

If by long you mean number of second or millisecond use this way.

LocalDateTime in Epoch seconds

```
val seconds = datetime.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochSecond())
```

LocalDateTime to epoch milliseconds

```
val milliseconds = datetime.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)?.toInstant()?.toEpochMilli()
```

Comment: The question is how to get a `long` value from a `LocalDateTime`, not the other way around shown here.

Comment: @Andreas Okay, I think long means epoch second. I don't understand your point accually.

Comment: I was looking at an old version of this answer, that converted a `seconds` value into a `LocalDateTime` value.

Comment: `atZone()` cannot return `null`, so why use `?.`? --- Why not use `datetime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)`? --- Why not use `datetime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()`?

Comment: @Andreas Maybe I miss something, I didn't find  `toInstant()` in this document https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/time/LocalDateTime

Comment: Expand "From class `ChronoLocalDateTime`" (below the method list). It's a `default` method from that interface.